# Error while using NetCDF: Invalid dimension ID or name

Tags: memory, memory-management, malloc, glibc, netcdf

I have installed NetCDF 4.3.2 and NetCDF-Fortran 4.2. I want to run Community Earth System Model 4.2.

When I create a case, build a case and then run a case, I get the following error:

`NetCDF: Invalid dimension ID or name
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011971760 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000012a3c5d0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011870e20 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011870e20 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011971760 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000129369d0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000129369d0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000012a3c5d0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000012ca7090 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011a16890 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000001101a390 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011e02f90 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000123df2b0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00000000128e7d30 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000012390540 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011db9ad0 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000012ca7090 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000012542e90 ***
*** glibc detected *** /home/nitin/CESM/NEW_CASES/CaseX/exeroot/cesm.exe: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000011e5dbb0 ***`

What exactly is wrong with the NetCDF installation?

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use CESM to test your netcdf installation.  use 'make check'.

Then, the backtrace you provided is pretty clear: you are passing garbage to one of your netcdf routines: probably passing a stack-allocated variable?  a missing command line argument?  You can get a better answer if you build CESM with debugging: you can then find which netcdf routine is giving you fits.

Comment: I used 'make check' to test the installation. It was fine. The error was because of the compiler optimization and a specific fortan file in the CESM code. Once I found the compatible fortran code, it worked. Thanks.